# Como hospedar minha aplicação angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, htaccess

Tenho os seguintes diretórios na minha aplicação em angular:

```
node_modules/
src/
--client/
----/app/
----/index.html
--server/
package.json
```

print dos arquivos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que quando o usuario acessase o meu site ele redirecionasse direto para a src/client/index.html e escondesse o src/client/.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Valeu.

Comment: Seria possível postar a arvore completa dos seus diretórios, e sua stack(arquivo de inicialização) do seu servidor nodejs(deduzo que seu backend seja node pelo 'node_modules/') ?

Comment: ainda não possuo nenhum server, mas vou postar o restante da arvore

Comment: Vc não precisa necessariamente usar o Node JS para servir sua aplicação.
Voce pode usar o Apache, Nginx, IIS ou qualquer outro webserver que lhe convenha visto que o angular roda na maquina cliente

Answer (score 4):

Usando Express em cima do NodeJS como servidor, você vai fazer o seguinte:

```
var express= require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../client/app'));

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('Servidor rodando!');
});
```

Usando o `express.static`, você vai dizer ao servidor qual a pasta pública da sua aplicação. O `__dirname` aponta para a pasta atual. No caso, supus que seu servidor vai ficar dentro da pasta `\server` e naveguei para cima com os dois pontos para, depois, entrar em `client/app`. Lá, por padrão, ele vai "servir" o arquivo com nome `index`.